# Comparing any values. from a list to what puts in the entry box in tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter

i want to to take information using entry widget and to compare and see if the input
in the entry box equals to one or more strings that i store inside a list
i tried :

```
if Entry.get() == any MyList[]:
          Mylable.pack()
```

also:

```
if Entry.get() == MyList[0:10]:
          MyLable.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the in operator, which can check if a value is present anywhere inside of a list:

```
if Entry.get() in MyList:
    Mylable.pack()
```

Or if you want to check to see if the entry text is in the first 10 elements of MyList:

```
if Entry.get() in MyList[0:10]:
    MyLable.pack()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , how can i do it to work if theres a full sentence in the entry box and i want it to detect a value from the list :

Comment: You'd have to split the entry data into multiple words using a `" "` as a delimiter. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp). Then, check to see if each word is present in MyList using the in operator.

Comment: okay so i tried if Entry.get().split(" ") in MyList: and it didnt worked it dosent detect the object in the list

Comment: Try this: ```words = Entry.get().split(" ")```. Then use a for loop to go through each word in words and see if it is in MyList.